# What do Seasoned Mac Users Do?

Tags: mac

I'm new to the Mac environment (learning it) and I'm coming from a 110% Windows backround.  I was wondering if people could chime in to let me know what "real" Mac users do.

Do they use:

1. iCal or Entourage
2. iWork or Office
3. iChat or Skype
4. Safari or Firefox
5. Mail or Thunderbird

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. iCal.
2. Mixture of both
3. Adium
4. Safari (ftw)
5. Mail

I also suggest CoRD, textmate, netnewswire, geektool, perian, VLC, transmit, Espresso, and Skitch, just for starters.

Give us more of an idea of what you're going to be doing day to day and I can probably make some other recommendations.

Comment: CoRD is new to me, thanks, I've used MS's RDC.  I'm curious to see how they compare.  I've been using FileZilla also, so I'll checkout transmit as well.  Smultron is a great (free) alternative to textmate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to "[Top 100 Mac Apps](http://chris.pirillo.com/top-100-mac-apps/)". The page will give you an idea about which software on Macs is popular, and which software you can use as a replacement to the ones on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Calendar (iCal caldav sync for iPhone)
2. Office (Google Docs for collaboration)
3. iChat (Adium is good also)
4. Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (in that order)
5. Gmail and Mail (Mail for MobileMe accounts)

I'm a Google & Apple fanboy, but this is where I fall on those 5 items.

Welcome to the Apple world.

Answer (score 0):

Mac users are as varied as any other set of people.  I've been using Apple computers since the 1980's, and my answers are completely different from the others so far:

1. Neither (sometimes Google Calendar, since my friends seem to publish their calendars on that)
2. Neither (Openoffice if someone sends me a file I need to open -- I bought MS Office once, and didn't like it)
3. Neither (I usually use IRC for chat)
4. Both, and also Chromium
5. Neither (GMail)